# Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind but for Rising Factorials

Tags: factorial, stirling-numbers

We know that, for instance, 
$$r^3=Ar(r-1)(r-2)+Br(r-1)+Cr+D$$
which can also be written as 
$$r^3=Ar^\underline{3}+Br^\underline{2}+Cr^\underline{1}+Dr^\underline{0}$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind $\big\lbrace {3\atop k}\big\rbrace$ for $k=3,2,1,0$ respectively, and are also coefficients of falling factorials.

> Is there a corresponding formula or name for the coefficients  in the case of rising factorials, e.g. $P,Q,R,S$ in 
>   $$r^3=Pr(r+1)(r+2)+Qr(r+1)+Rr+S$$
>   which can also be written as 
>   $$r^3=Pr^\overline{3}+Qr^\overline{2}+Rr^\overline{1}+Sr^\overline{0}$$
>   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that a monomial can be expressed as a linear combination of falling factorials and the coefficients are the Stirling numbers of the second kind
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \big\lbrace {n\atop k}\big\rbrace r^\underline{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
In order to express a monomial as a linear combination of rising factorials just replace $\color{red}{r \rightarrow -r}$; note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^\underline{k}=r(r-1)\cdots (r-k+1) \rightarrow (-r)(-r-1) \cdots (-r-k+1) =(-1)^k r^\overline{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So the formula you seek is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \big\lbrace {n\atop k}\big\rbrace r^\overline{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Nice solution (+1). So the coefficients are in fact signed Stirling numbers of the second kind.